# GmailConnect In Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, google-apps

I'm working on Drupal 6 and trying to access user mail from Google A/c on my profile page. I'm using GmailConnect Module http://drupal.org/project/gmail_connect for implementing this functionality. I've configured it properly with proper Consumer Key/Secret Key.

Please help me out.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have IMAP enabled in firstly in your google apps domain control panel, and secondly in the individual user account settings.